# SQL : Order by when a value looks like a date

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
Table  :
Value:
gte
2016-06-07
aze
2015-07-08
(...)
```

Important :
Value stores Varchar (because it can be a string, a number, a date etc...)

I need to "sort by" the value that look like a date 
Something that i imagine like this ?

```
ORDER BY (value LIKE "%Y-%m-%d") DESC
```

Comment: You should think about your database design

Comment: I can't because this is from a CMS Module...

Answer (score 0):

If the date is formatted as you describe as **YYYY-MM-DD**, you just need to remove the - separator. It is then sortable as a string into numeric order.

Try something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY REPLACE(Value,'-','') DESC
```

Comment: this is not what he want

Comment: Problem is that value can be anything (including a number or a string with a "-" in it). So it won't only match the values taht "look like" date.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to convert it to date you will get null for other none date values

example

```
mysql> mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('5/15/2012 8:06:26 AM','%c/%e/%Y %r');
+---------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('5/15/2012 8:06:26 AM','%c/%e/%Y %r') |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-05-15 08:06:26                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('dfsddfs','%c/%e/%Y %r');
+--------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('dfsddfs','%c/%e/%Y %r') |
+--------------------------------------+
| NULL                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

1st try to convert it to date and get not null results and the sort using ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(value, "%Y-%e-%c") AS DT FROM TABLE) T WHERE T.DT IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DT;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should order a recordset by placing all the "date-looking" values at the top. It uses a RegEx pattern in the "LIKE" clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT VALUE,
case when VALUE LIKE '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' then 1 else 0 END AS LOOKS_LIKE_DATE
FROM TABLE

) ORDER BY LOOKS_LIKE_DATE DESC
```